# Change UI / run function of MainWindow from another window Task

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I need to make one thing quite complicated, which worked with Forms and not with WPF, and I have no idea why.

I have to call a function of the main window of the WPF program through a Task of the second window:

```
task[0] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).status_running();
    return 0;
});
```

In practice, this function changes different label, but nothing happens if the task. Instead if it is out this way:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).status_running();
task[0] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return 0;
});
```

It seems to work. The problem, therefore, is presented in the task, the same problem if I insert the code in a thread.

Comment: Why do you need a `Factory.SartNew`?  I think you could directly call that UI function after awaiting a previous non-UI task...

Comment: The biggest problem is that I have the same kind of issue also in the threads, andcan not avoid them. @MachineLearning

Comment: Can you show more code? What is the content of status_running()? are both windows wpf xaml? etc..

Comment: Both are Xaml Windows, the content of status_running is 2 label.Text = "string"; for now. And, I don't know how to show more code with a comment, sorry :( But I can say that a button i the main window open the second window, the second window do some stuff and then change ui with a series of 30 tasks every time it finish a job. @MachineLearning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the UI Thread `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

```
task[0] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).status_running();
                return 0;
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: And what if I want to attach a FinalTask?

Comment: @Northumber Do you mean a [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx)? That's a possibility. Or a [WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) maybe if you have more than one task to wait for...

Comment: No, I mean Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll

Comment: Ok, it's a similar thing: you have to choose the correct scheduler (as above) if you need to update the ui

Comment: I've got a problem, the tasks change the UI only when all finishes, what to do?

Comment: you have to clarify - in the question - what is your expected result and what is your current code, with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)